# javascript can not iterate array after reading JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am new in javascript. I am having problem with simple json file reading. Here is the sample code.

```
   function readJson() {
        $.getJSON('./resources/json/comments_type.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, comment) {
                tempList.push(comment);
            });
        });



        for(var i = 0 ; i<tempList.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(tempList[i].text);
        }

    }
```

Here I was trying to iterate the tempList array after reading from the JSON file. But the console.log is not showing anything. But if I try `console.log(tempList)` it works. `tempList`is a global variable. I am calling the `readJson` function from another function. The JSON file saved here [JSON file](https://jsonblob.com/54d3211de4b0488219ac83b9)

Comment: Could you post how you created tempList? Did you (by mistake) used { } insted of [ ] ?

Comment: Thanks for that. I have checked. I used tempList = []

Comment: Could you edit where you have this code? It seems that there is something with the scope

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readJSON function is called asynchronously. It means it is loading JSON from url (in another thread) when you already started to console.log content of tempList. Make sure that you read temp list after downloading it. It is usually done by callback. Or you could make this request synchronous (but it is wrong approach).

```
function readJson() {
    $.getJSON('./resources/json/comments_type.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, comment) {
            tempList.push(comment);
        });
       for(var i = 0 ; i<tempList.length;i++)
       {
          console.log(tempList[i].text);
       }
    });     
 }
```

Try this way. You should get printed list. You could also pass callback to readJson function:

```
    function readJson(callback) {
    $.getJSON('./resources/json/comments_type.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, comment) {
            tempList.push(comment);
        });
       callback();
    });     
 }
```

And then somewhere else in the code:

```
readJson(function(){
    for(var i = 0 ; i<tempList.length;i++)
       {
          console.log(tempList[i].text);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running the for loop before you actually get any data as $.getJSON is asyncronous. So try moving the iterator loop to the $.getJSON callback.

```
function readJson() {
    $.getJSON('./resources/json/comments_type.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, comment) {
            tempList.push(comment);
        });

        //Here you should have the list
        for(var i = 0 ; i<tempList.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(tempList[i].text);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! I forgot about the asynchronous calling in js.